# How to display edge lneghts on non-highlighted edges?

Tags: modeling, interface

When I'm in edit mode, I can use the N menu to toggle on the edge info Length option.
This is great, but the problem is that I need to see the length of the edge while I'm edge beveling a vert. (crl+shift+b).
[image]

Is there some way to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: you mean that when you bevel edge you need to display the length

Comment: If you bevel a vertex with Ctrl+Shift+B the length of the edges surronding that vertex, including those created by the bevel, will be shown.

Answer (score 1):

In the N panel Under Mesh Display
Click on the length
And active on Normal (i.e. vertex, edge, face) what length you want to view
If you click on the vertex it show the vertex, etc
[image]

[image]

Comment: It works for most cases, but if you try to bevel a single vertex on a flat plane. (Make a flat plane, select one corner vertex and do ctrl+shift+b) then it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Download the addon Measureit [here](https://github.com/Antonioya/blender/blob/master/measureit/measureit_v1_6_7.zip)

After installation in the tools panel

[image]

Click on the Hide and show toggle button (click on show)

Bake the bevel to the vertex ctrl+shift+b and select all (press twice a) and you will get all the measurements

[image]

Comment: That is the problem, I need to see the length DURING the beveling process since I need to bevel that edge to an exact length. The lneghts displays fine after I finish the beveling even without the addon, but  it never shows during beveling.